# Pygame problems - I try to close the window, the image blits, then unblits...what?

Tags: python, image, pygame, window

Well this is a weird situation.

So I'm trying to make a game in python, and it requires me to blit a picture of a character (name's Minty, just clarifying for the code), and I did it the regular way anyone would. However, this happens:

I run the code. The Pygame window opens. So far so good.
There is no image however.
There is no traceback.
I try to X out and kill the program. Then the image suddenly appears.
Wait, what?

Why is this happening?
Has this happened to anyone?
Here's my code (I cut out all unnecessary bits.)

```
import sys
import time
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
#MAIN GAME LOOP
while True:

    for events in pygame.event.get():
        if events.type == QUIT:
            quit()
            exit()

    #INITIALISING THE WINDOW. kept this in case anyone decides to try this out
    #CONSTANTS ARE CAPITAL, VARIABLES ARE LOWERCASE
    SCREENWIDTH = 900
    SCREENHEIGHT = 600
    SCREENSIZE = [SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT]
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREENSIZE)
    BG_COL = [255, 123, 67]
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    screen.fill(BG_COL)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

    #INITIALISE ALL OBJECTS.

    class Opponent(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self, name, title, sprite):
            self.name = name
            self.title = title
            self.sprite = sprite

    #INITIALISING CHARACTERS.

    Minty = Opponent("Minty Portal", "Fairy of Many Worlds", pygame.image.load("Portraits/minty-normal.png"))

    #BLIT CHARACTER
    screen.blit(Minty.sprite, [300, 90])
    pygame.display.update()
```

I don't know if I'm posting this right, any edits I should make, please comment below.
Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are redefining the screen variable every gameloop in the main function. I would recommend to initialize the window outside of the main gameloop.
Try initializing everything that you only want initialized once, outside of the main gameloop.